# Parse XML from shell - python

Tags: python, xml, shell, parsing

I need to parse an xml from the shell.
When I send the command

```
telnet IP_addr port
```

so from a python script I do:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

where cmd is my command.

I obtain an XML that I have to parse
This is my output:

```
Trying 10.1.6.123...
Connected to 10.1.6.123.
Escape character is '^]'.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="14">
<g>
        <V>13</V>
        <E>34</E>
        <node>
                <name>172.16.102.116</name>
                <id>172.16.102.116</id>
                <regen_pools>
                        <count>0</count>
                        <item_version>0</item_version>
                </regen_pools>
                <osnr_db>0.000000000e+00</osnr_db>
                <osnr>
                        <count>0</count>
                        <item_version>0</item_version>
                </osnr>
        </node>
....
```

I have already wrote the code to parse that when it is saved into a file, removing the first three lines.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('topo.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
graph={}
app=[]
for vertex in root.findall('g/node'):
    key = vertex.find('id').text
```

But the xml is passed as a file. How to do it whitout create a file?

Thanks a lot
Silvia

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving the XML string to a file directly read it using **[xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring)**

**EX:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xmlstring))
```

**Sample Code**

```
xmlData = '''<Tables>
<Table><Claimable>false</Claimable><MinorRev>80601</MinorRev><Operation>530600 ION MILL</Operation><HTNum>162</HTNum><WaferEC>80318</WaferEC><HolderType>HACARR</HolderType><Job>167187008</Job></Table>
<Table><Claimable>false</Claimable><MinorRev>71115</MinorRev><Operation>530600 ION MILL</Operation><Experiment>6794</Experiment><HTNum>162</HTNum><WaferEC>71105</WaferEC><HolderType>HACARR</HolderType><Job>16799006</Job></Table>
</Tables>
'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xmlData))
root = tree.getroot()
print root
```

Comment: in your case you have a "variable" that you call xmlData in your python script, if I'm not wrong. 
What I would like to do is read the xml directly from the shell output - I'm sending the command to "print" the xml from the script with subprocess

Comment: @user2907822 from the desc you are stripping the first 3 lines and saving it to a file correct?

Comment: no, I've saved the output with
telnet ip 8881 |tee namefile.xml
and manually removed the first 3 lines